# ¿Es posible usar SCOPE_IDENTITY en un update?¿Alternativas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Uso `SCOPE_IDENTITY` para recuperar la id de la inserción y así poder trabajar con el. Por lo tanto se que con las `insert` funciona.

La pregunta es, ¿funciona con las `update`? He probado a seguir un proceso similar y devuelve nulo.

En caso de que no funcione, ¿alguna manera de hacerlo? ¿Tengo que declarar variables y setearlas?

Ejemplo de una update no funcional:

```
UPDATE
       [XXX].[dbo].[FirmanteActaModeloGeneral]
Set    [Tratamiento]               = 'D.'
     , [NombreFirmante]            = 'NombreFirmante'
     , [Apellido1Firmante]         = 'Apellido1Firmante'
     , [Apellido2Firmante]         = 'Apellido2Firmante'
     , [CargoFirmante]             = 'CargoFirmante'
     , [PosicionFirmaActaAraba]    = 0
     , [PosicionFirmaActaBizkaia]  = 0
     , [PosicionFirmaActaGipuzkoa] = 0
WHERE
       IdFirmante =30;

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): *Returns the last identity value **inserted** into an identity column in the same scope*. Es decir, el último `valor de identity` insertado, no sirve para las sentencias e `UPDATE`.

Pero, puedes usar la clausula [`OUTPUT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) junto con el `UPDATE`. por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @UpdatedValues table(  
    IdFirmante int NOT NULL
)

UPDATE
       [XXX].[dbo].[FirmanteActaModeloGeneral]
Set    [Tratamiento]               = 'D.'
     , [NombreFirmante]            = 'NombreFirmante'
     , [Apellido1Firmante]         = 'Apellido1Firmante'
     , [Apellido2Firmante]         = 'Apellido2Firmante'
     , [CargoFirmante]             = 'CargoFirmante'
     , [PosicionFirmaActaAraba]    = 0
     , [PosicionFirmaActaBizkaia]  = 0
     , [PosicionFirmaActaGipuzkoa] = 0
WHERE
       IdFirmante =30
OUTPUT inserted.IdFirmante  
       INTO @UpdatedValues;  

SELECT * FROM UpdatedValues;
```

Detalle:

- El `OUTPUT` permite registrar cualquier valor anterior `deleted` o posterior `inserted`
- Podemos, si lo buscamos, registrar la fila completa indicando todas las columnas
- Podríamos usar también una tabla física para registrar los valores.
- Estoy asumiendo que `IdFirmante` es el `identity`.